# How to edit nested objects in Spring and Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

There is the Base entity:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
}
```

There is the Name entity:

```
public class Name extends BaseEntity {
    private String en;
    private String de;
    private String fr;
}
```

There is the Element entity:

```
public class Element extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Name name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Category> category;
}
```

There is the Category entity:

```
public class Category extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Name name;
}
```

There is the edit Element form in thymeleaf:

```
<form method="post" th:object="${element}" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/elements/edit(id=${element.id})}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Element name (en, de, fr)</label>
        <div  class="input-group flex-container">
              <input type="text" name="name.en" th:value="${element.name.en}" placeholder="(EN)"/>
              <input type="text" name="name.de" th:value="${element.name.hu}" placeholder="(DE)"/>
              <input type="text" name="name.fr" th:value="${element.name.ro}" placeholder="(FR)"/>
        </div>
    </div>

// BELOW IS THE PROBLEM: (the rest of the form works properly) 
    <div th:each="ctg : ${element.category}" class="form-group">
        <label>Category</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{ctg.name}" name="en" th:value="${ctg.name.en}" placeholder="en"/>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{ctg.name}" name="de" th:value="${ctg.name.de}" placeholder="(de)"/>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{ctg.name}" name="fr" th:value="${ctg.name.fr}" placeholder="(fr)"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have tried all kinds of edit forms for the Element entity, but I can not edit the Name coresponding to the Category entity. So how should the form be configured in the category section?